# Markdown to use CSS and still retain markdown formatting

Tags: html, css, markdown

I want to use an external CSS file for my markdown.

I added this at the top of my file:

```
<link href="./src/css/main.scss" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

And was able to use CSS classes.  But my problem is when I use a CSS class, it completely overwrites the markdown and the markdown formatting is gone.

For example I want to have a code section with font color red, I tried this:

````
<span markdown="1" class="font-red" >
```bash
quasar dev```
</span>
````

But this prints out the entire line in red. CSS overwrites the markdown formatting:

` ``bash quasar dev```

I tried to change it to:

```` ```bash
<span markdown="1" class="font-red" >
quasar dev
</span> ````
 ```

But this prints the  tag as text. This time, markdown formatting overwrites the CSS.

So how can I achieve a mixture of markdown and CSS format?
A code section where its font is color red?

Help please! Thanks

Comment: A reproducible example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the markdown syntax. Markdown isn't parsed inside inline HTML. You need to recreate the HTML elements yourself.

Plus, you can't put block-level elements inside a inline-level element (like `<span>`).

Use this:

```html
<pre markdown="1" class="font-red"><code>bash
quasar dev</code></pre>
```